# Write Special characters in a file

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, eps

I am trying to write data in a .eps file, Here is my code

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');'`

`$var = 'ê';`

`echo $var;`

`$file = 'test.eps';`

`file_put_contents($file, $var);`

But when i open test.eps, the data written is `Ãª` it should have been `ê`

Please Help ...

Comment: Is your source file encoding properly set to UTF8? You should check it in your text editor.

Comment: How do you open the file? Perhaps it is saved right, but shown wrong in your viewer (vim etc.). On what kind of system are your files located? Unix, Windwos

Comment: Its located on Windows...When i open the file with wordpad the text is converted there as well ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are dealing with either:

1. The character encoding of the source code file you have created (make sure it is UTF-8!)
2. The default encoding for file_put_contents is utf8, so you should be okay there but your OS or distro might be interfering.  What OS / distro / version are you using?

**Edit**
From the comments it sounds like an issue with your text editor.  Try creating a new copy of the file using a proper programming text editor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173112/best-lightweight-ide-text-editor

Comment: When i save the file as txt it works fine but having problems with .eps file ... Working on Windows

Comment: The file extension you choose should not affect things.  More likely, some part of your toolchain is creating a non-UTF8 file.  You can use a program like [`file`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) to check if your files are UTF-8.  Fwiw I tried this on OS X and it worked fine.  Running `file` on my local `test.eps` returns `test.eps:  UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators`.

Comment: The other possibility, I forgot to mention, is that the program you are opening the `test.eps` file with are interpreting the file as though it were non-UTF8.  Also (I'm not sure if this is the issue), don't use notepad.exe or wordpad.exe I wouldn't trust those to handle fine grained issues with character encoding.

Comment: Yeah you are right... wordpad was making a mess of it.On Notepad++ it is fine.But the issue is still there, the default program for test.eps is Adobe illustratoe CS3, when i open it in that it shows `ˆ“`

Comment: That I can't help you with much unfortunately. Perhaps your output does not conform to the EPS standards? Perhaps try some basic sample EPS files and work from there? This might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript