# writing special characters to txt file

Tags: php

I am reading some data from a remote file, got every thing working till the point when i write some specific lines to a text file.
problem here is, when i write something like **Girl's Goldtone 'X' CZ Ring** it becomes ***Girl & apos;s Goldtone &apos ;X & apos; CZ Ring*** in txt file.
how do i write to txt file so that it retains text like written above and not show character code but actual character.
sample of my code.

```
$content_to_write = '<li class="category-top"><span class="top-span"><a class="category-top" href="'.$linktext.'.html">'.$productName.'</a></span></li>'."\r\n";
                fwrite($fp, $content_to_write);  
$linktext = "Girls-Goldtone-X-CZ-Ring";  
$productName = "Girl's Goldtone 'X' CZ Ring";
```

**var_dump**

```
string '<li class="category-top"><span class="top-span"><a class="category-top" href="Stellar-Steed-Gallery-wrapped-Canvas-Art.html">&apos;Stellar Steed&apos; Gallery-wrapped Canvas Art</a></span></li>
```

' (length=195)

**Code**

```
                $productName =$linktext;


                $linktext = str_replace(" ", "-", $linktext);
                $delChar = substr($linktext, -1);
                if($delChar == '.')
                {
                    $linktext = substr($linktext, 0, -1);
                }

                $linktext = removeRepeated($linktext);
                $linktext = remove_invalid_char($linktext);
                $productName = html_entity_decode($productName);
                $content_to_write = '<li class="category-top"><span class="top-span"><a class="category-top" href="'.$linktext.'.html">'.$productName.'</a></span></li>'."\r\n";
                var_dump($content_to_write);
                fwrite($fp, utf8_encode($content_to_write));
```

Comment: That's proberblay just a matter of encoding. Which encoding is used in the external file, which is used when viewing the output and which one is used when writing to the .txt file?

Answer (score 2):

Is it that you are reading the data from a remote file and then writing the same to a txt file? Agree with the above comment, its an issue with encoding. Try the following code:

```
$file = file_get_contents("messages.txt");
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
echo $file;
```

echo the response to your browser and see. If found proper, write the response to your txt file. Ensure that your txt file is UTF8 - encoded.

Check this out::  [Write Special characters in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602573/write-special-characters-in-a-file).

Comment: thanks, but i didn't solve the problem.  i am reading a txt file from url and then reading a random line via **fgets** this line shows correct on the browser but when i write this line to txt via **fwrite** it messes up all special characters.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` is binary-safe, meaning it doesn't do any encoding stuff but just writes whatever you feed it directly to the file. It looks like the `$productName` variable you're writing is already entity-encoded before writing. Try running [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) over the variable first.

Note that `html_entity_decode` doesn't touch single quotes (`&apos;`) by default; you'll have to set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag in the second parameter. You might also want to explicitly specify an encoding in the third parameter.

Comment: sorry my bad, i corrected $productName.  but my variable gets value from an array. which i a random line read from remote file. every thing seems fine on browser but but in txt the problem is still there.

Comment: yeah, i've been trying for about 2 days now. but nothing seems to work.  is there a platform issue or some thing, i am on win 7 64bit, WAMP. does it has to do any thing with that.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan: could you show us the actual code you're using plus a `var_dump()` of the data you're writing (just before actually writing it)?

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan: check my updated answer, does modifying the quotes mode solve the problem?

Comment: still no change, and i can't even see any encoding on the txt file. how do make sure that txt file written with fwrite is encoded.